# How to play a radio station on button press in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer, internet-radio

I want to play a radio station when someone presses the play radio button. However, it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.radio.net.pk/"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];
[audio play];
```

Comment: have a look this demo :-https://github.com/hamedh/Radio

Comment: Thanks for giving me help.Kindly tell me how i can change my link in this demo.So that when app start then it should stream my radio statio sound.

Comment: search with "http" in demo project then replace your link with demo link

Comment: Dear,i have replaced my http link with that link but did not buffered.Please send me some other links of radio to try.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AVAudioPlayer` class only lets you play sound in any audio format available in iOS and OS X

This means, the `AVAudioPlayer` class does not provide support for streaming audio based on HTTP URL's. The URL used with `initWithContentsOfURL:` must be a local path URL.

So you should save the NSData locally (with different chunks) and play it using  `AVAudioPlayer`.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work ever.

Does **radio.net.pk** offers any APIs?

`datWithContentsOfURL` will return **HTML string** that you are trying to play using `AVAudioPlayer` !!. Please go through the website again and check for any **developer API**.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Using this Cannel

NSURL *url6 = [NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://sc6.spacialnet.com:35464/"]
layerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:_strTemp]; // add url to playerItem

player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem]; // add player item to AVAudioPlayer
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:_strTemp]
```